# How to do inference with tensorflow2 with multi GPUs

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2

I have a large dateset to inference. There are 10 gpus in my machine. When I do inference, only one GPU work. The frame I use is tensorflow2.6. I used to use pytorch. But now I have to use tensorflow which I am not familiar with for some reasons.

I want to know how to use all gpus and keep the order of the Dataset at the same time in the inference process